# Using slug as a filter with Graphql and Strapi V4

Tags: graphql, strapi

Trying to use slug as an uuid to fetch single pages from a strapi backend v4.
my query to get pages works well. It's just I can't filter using slug:

my pages query:

```json
  query {
   pages {
    data {
      attributes {
            Name
            slug
      }
    }
 }
}
```

how to get single page using `slug` uuid within this schema ? every trails to implement ($slug: String!) fails as where to locate slug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use filters. Just pass slug as argument and use the 'eq' keyword for comparison which stands for equals.

```
query pages($slug:String) {
    pages(filters:{slug:{eq:$slug}}) {
        data {
            attributes {
                Name
                slug
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
query pages($id: ID) {
  page(id: $id) {
    data {
      attributes {
        name
        slug
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

base on this blog, from strapi, a resolver must be coded

[I Found a Blog for strapi v4](https://strapi.io/blog/extending-and-building-custom-resolvers-with-strapi-v4)

Comment: But how adapt the resolver to be compatible with i18n ([Adapt GraphQL-Strapi slug custom resolver for i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965796/adapt-graphql-strapi-slug-custom-resolver-for-i18n)) ?