# Adapt GraphQL-Strapi slug custom resolver for i18n

Tags: graphql, request, internationalization, strapi

I've found a [very good tutorial to create a GraphQL custom resolver with Strapi](https://strapi.io/blog/extending-and-building-custom-resolvers-with-strapi-v4) (for slug parameter).
Unfortunately, I can't adapt the code to be compatible with multi languages (i18n). Here is my actual code:

```js
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  register({ strapi }) {
    const extensionService = strapi.service("plugin::graphql.extension");
    extensionService.use(({ strapi }) => ({
      typeDefs: `
        type Query {
          article(slug: String!, locale: I18NLocaleCode): ArticleEntityResponse
        }
      `,
      resolvers: {
        Query: {
          article: {
            resolve: async (parent, args, context) => {
              const { toEntityResponse } = strapi.service(
                "plugin::graphql.format"
              ).returnTypes;

              const data = await strapi.services["api::article.article"].find({
                filters: { slug: args.slug, locale: args.locale },
              });

              const response = toEntityResponse(data.results[0]);

              console.log("##################", response, "##################");

              return response;
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }));
  },
};
```

When I make a GraphQL request, I am getting an empty response.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for this or not? I have the same problem

Comment: @SandervanMaastricht, I have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the article helped me on Strapi forum and resolved the problem. Here the discussion : https://forum.strapi.io/t/how-to-extend-and-build-custom-resolvers-with-strapi-v4/20891/6 
He is not using `strapi.service`, but `strapi.db.query`, and it is solving the problem. 
Here is the new code that is working:

```js
"use strict";

const boostrap = require("./bootstrap");

module.exports = {
  async bootstrap() {
    await boostrap();
  },

  register({ strapi }) {
    const extensionService = strapi.service("plugin::graphql.extension");
    extensionService.use(({ strapi }) => ({
      typeDefs: `
        type Query {
          article(slug: String!, locale: I18NLocaleCode): ArticleEntityResponse
        }
      `,
      resolvers: {
        Query: {
          article: {
            resolve: async (parent, args, context) => {
              const { toEntityResponse } = strapi.service(
                "plugin::graphql.format"
              ).returnTypes;

              // const data = await strapi.services["api::article.article"].find({
              //   filters: { slug: args.slug, locale: args.locale },
              // });

              const data = await strapi.db.query("api::article.article").findMany({
                where: { locale: args.locale, slug: args.slug }
              });

              // console.log("##################", data.results, "##################");


              const response = toEntityResponse(data[0]);
              // const response = toEntityResponse(data.results[0]);

              console.log("##################", response, "##################");

              return response;
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }));
  },
};
```